# ASP.NET Roles not being assigned to users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have a site that I want to differentiate between ASP.NET Identity users and External Users using roles.

I have created my roles using:

```
    ApplicationDbContext.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole()
    {
        Name = "External"
    });
    ApplicationDbContext.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole()
    {
        Name = "Internal"
    });
    ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

These roles get added to the aspnetRoles Table correctly.

Then in my AccountController for Internal users I use the Register Post action:

```
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Internal");
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
...
```

Which adds a record to the aspnetUsers table, and another to the aspnetUserRoles table with the User ID matching the new user and the Role ID matching the corresponding role.

I then do the same for my External registrations:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.userName, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "External");
            result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}
```

Which does exactly the same thing, creates the user in the DB and adds matching IDs to the UserRoles table.

However, when I log in using either method and try to navigate to an action with `[Authorize(Roles="Internal")]` or `[Authorize(Roles="External")]` I cannot access them. 
I added a test using `ApplicationUser CurrentUser = UserManager.FindByName("MyUserName");`
which successfully returns my user from the database, but when I then say `Console.WriteLine(CurrentUser.Roles);` the `CurrentUser.Roles` has a count of 0, which makes it look like the role was not assigned correctly.

Is there something I have missed in the assigning role process? 
I cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

***Edit***
Answer / Further question...

When adding the users to roles using the above, the users id is added to the `UserId` column of the `UserRoles` table, but there was a third column called `IdentityUser_Id` which was always null.

Out of curiosity I added my user id to that column as well and now the everything works. the application picked up my user role.

My follow up question to this is can I set the `IdentityUser_Id` automatically? using something similar to the `UserManager.AddToRole()` which adds the userId to both columns?

thanks

Comment: Your project may be also using the legacy role manager functionality. Try addin `<roleManager enabled="false">....</roleManager>` into your `web.config`.

Comment: Under `<System.Web>`? I also noticed it has this: `<authentication mode="None" />` is that right? It is a standard MVC5 project with Individual User Accounts

Comment: That's something different and not related to Identity. Did disabling the role manager help?

Comment: Ok, No it did not, the `UserManager.GetRoles()` still returns 0 and `User.IsInRole("Internal")` returns false

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my similar code looks like. I use the role manager to create the roles:

```
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

            // Add missing roles
            var role = roleManager.FindByName("External");
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new IdentityRole("External");
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }
            role = roleManager.FindByName("Internal");
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new IdentityRole("Internal");
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }

            // Create test users
            var user = userManager.FindByName("admin");
            if (user == null)
            {
                var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "admin",
                    FirstName = "Admin",
                    LastName = "User",
                    Email = "xxx.xxx@xxx.net",
                    PhoneNumber = "5555559492",
                    MustChangePassword = false
                };
                userManager.Create(newUser, "Password1");
                userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(newUser.Id, false);
                userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "Internal");
            }
            user = userManager.FindByName("limited");
            if (user == null)
            {
                var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "limited",
                    FirstName = "Limited",
                    LastName = "User",
                    Email = "limited@mypd.com",
                    PhoneNumber = "6085555556",
                    MustChangePassword = false
                };
                userManager.Create(newUser, "Password1");
                userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(newUser.Id, false);
                userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "External");
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I copy/pasted your code exactly and am getting the same thing. Users and Roles are created in the database, but when you add a `user.Roles` line and break on it `user.Roles` contains 0.

Comment: See if you have a rolemanager reference in web.config. Shouldn't need anything in there with identity 2.